# Remembering scroll position in all pages with PHP session when using menu buttons

Tags: php, javascript, session, scroll, position

My page has a horizontal top menu bar with a logo at the top of it. Because of the logo, visitors will scroll down slightly. When using the menu, I don't want the page to annoyingly jump up to the top.

How can I maintain the window scroll position when the visitor clicks another top menu button only, throughout the whole page?

Answer (score 1):

"My page has a horizontal top menu bar with a logo at the top of it. Because of the logo, visitors will scroll down slightly"

Isn't that frustrating for the user? and the solution you are suggesting makes things even worse and more weird, I think you seriously need to reconsider your design.

However if you insist on your solution you should use JavaScript, read the [window.ScrollY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.scrollY) store it in a [cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp) then read back the cookie on the new page and use [window.scrollTo()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp) function to scroll to the old position.

Comment: The case isn't probably as bad as you think. This is what it looks like:
http://experiencerapanui.com/index.php

Why would remembering the window position when pressing menu buttons be bad and wierd?

Comment: Because the user doesn't expect it to happen. It breaks user's browsing habits and most of the times that is not a good thing. Now that I'm looking at your website I'm wondering why would anybody need to scroll down to use the menus? Your website looks fine and useable to me the way it is.